# Getting GPS data in the Broadcast receiver when program is running in background in android

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, sms, sharedpreferences

I've been struggling with a problem and it's driving me crazy! I'm trying to get GPS location by SMS. for this, I'm using a broadcast receiver to get the request SMS and if it wants my location, I send the latitude and longitude by again a SMS. To get the GPS location I did this in main activity (I'm using a googleMapV2 example):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.location.LocationListener{
    // Google Map
    public static GoogleMap googleMap;
    public static double gpsLatitude = 0;
    public static double gpsLongitude = 0;
        ...
}
```

and at the end of main file, in the **onLocationChanged()** method:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("GPSData", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
    edit.putLong("latitude", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(location.getLatitude())).apply();
    edit.putLong("longitude", double.doubleToRawLongBits(location.getLongitude())).apply();
    edit.commit();      
    edit.apply();

    gpsLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    gpsLongitude = location.getLongitude();

}
```

as you can see I'm setting the location in both SharedPreferences and a static variable. To keep the cpu running, I added WAKE_LOC in main activity:

```
PowerManager pm;
PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        context = getApplicationContext();      

        pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Power Management");

        wl.acquire();
```

and when I press a button named Exit, I use wl.release() to stop using the power.
In my broadcast receiver I can read both of these data when application is running and everything work fine; the problem is when I'm trying to get the Location when application is not running in front. I placed this in **onBackPressed()** method:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);           
}
```

and my application is really working in background. The GPS starts to get the location and I see that it locks on location. I also added marker in **onLocationChanged()** method and I started to move. When I was back to my application I see a trial of markers on the path that I moved on. So I'm sure that the GPS is working fine and the data is valid when application is running in background. The problem occurs  when I want to get the location by SMS. Again, when the application is running foreground, the SMS works fine too, but when I press the back button, it seems that the **static data** and **SharedPreferences** won't update their value anymore! It keeps the last location and even when I move, it won't change.
Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.